# Set icon when content scripts of extension are active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My Extension works in specific sites and I want the user to know when it's working.
I've specified specific pages for my content scripts in the manifest,

How do i change my extension icon when content scripts are active?

*(Edit from author's comment)*
Although my app will work on specific pages, i still want the user to be able to view the pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented just that for my extension [Grooveshark Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grooveshark-control/jjhlhcmfkkhnikmehakaceciakbppoij). It's pretty simple. I injected script to page which I need and from that injected script I periodically call my extension with some data.

```
// content.js
setInterval(dataCollector, 1000)

function dataCollector() {
    data = {} // collect something from page
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(data);
}
```

And in my extension I just listen for that…

```
// background.js
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request) {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon(...)
})
```

But with this you can have some troubles. For example someone could disable and again enable your extension. Then it's good to `content.js` also register `responseCallback` in which you will remove that interval. Because then there would be two requests. This problem is mostly during development when you need reload your extension.

Another thing is that user could close tab with your page and now you need to again change your icon. For that you need to use another listener in your `background.js` script:

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId, removeInfo) {
    // check if your page is still there
    // if not, change icon
})
```

Code of Grooveshark Control is on GitHub, so you can check it out:

- [`contentscript.js`](https://github.com/horejsek/groovesharkControl/blob/master/groovesharkControl/javascript/contentscript/contentscript.coffee)
- [`background.js`](https://github.com/horejsek/groovesharkControl/blob/master/groovesharkControl/javascript/background/background.coffee)
- [Some used functions.](https://github.com/horejsek/groovesharkControl/blob/master/groovesharkControl/javascript/groovesharkControl/groovesharkControl.coffee)

Hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**While ideologically correct, this is not a good answer, as it does not answer the question OP really has. If someone could contribute a robust solution to change the browser action icon for particular pages, it would be welcome.**

As per Chrome UI guidelines, you should employ a [Page Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction) when your extension makes sense only for specific sites.

The most straightforward solution is to send a message from the content script to a background script to show the page action for a specific tab, and report a click back to the tab:

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({showAction : true});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.actionClicked) {
      /* Do stuff */
    }
  }
);
```

---

```
// background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(message.showAction) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }
  }
);

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {actionClicked : true});
});
```

You will need to add required fields to the manifest, but that's the gist of it.

---

You could also consider another route: instead of injecting the script every time, detect pages you want to inject to with [`declarativeContent` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) to show the page action, and inject programmatically on click. That would save some resources, but does not apply if you need to do preparations on the page.

Comment: thanks for replying, and sorry for not mentioning this - although my app will work on specific pages, i still want the user to be able to view the pop up, if the app is page action, will this be possible?

Comment: No, you probably would want to stick to `browserAction` then. You still can send a message from the content script, and in the background script use `chrome.browserAction.setIcon({tabId: sender.tab.id, path: "yourSpecialIcon.png"})`

Comment: Hm, but then there is a problem of navigating away.

Comment: true, the other alternative is to check every page if it's in my supported sites. But that will require permission to all sites.